# JavaScript object function disappeared after reassigning the object's prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Here's the code:

```
function ClassName() { }
var cnObj = new ClassName();
ClassName.prototype.func = function() { console.log("hello"); }
cnObj.func(); // => "hello"
ClassName.prototype = new Object();
cnObj.func(); // => undefined
```

If we do not explicitly specify the prototype JavaScript uses Object by default. So when I add the new function `func` to the `ClassName` it works fine. But is the function `func` somehow deleted from the prototype when I specify `Object` as the `ClassName` prototype?

This question is a bit similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078759/object-method-gone-after-obj-prototype-new-parentobj-in-javascript) but the difference is that here I use the same prototype as before adding new function `func`.

Comment: Nothing disappears. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dxoy9rmh/). You're probably running in a developer console, and didn't notice that `"hello"` has a `2` on the same line. The `undefined` is the return value of your function. Only the new `ClassName` objects you make after the `ClassName.prototype = new Object()` will be affected by the change.

Comment: Of course it disappears... the prototype is a live reference.. when you re-assigned it.... you removed the "func" method.. so, when you called cnObj.func().. it looks on "cnObj's" prototype... not there,, so it looks on ClassName... oh, not there.. you over-written it.

Comment: Ran it with node.js - "hello" got printed twice